# creating new entities in Backbone Marionette for related models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I've built the backbone app with one model ("conference"). Now I added second model ("talk"). talks belongs to conference, conference has many talks. The nested json is created and it is easy to render it into single-conference template  with .eco like this:

I can basically build nested json and render nested attributes, no problem but is it a good architecture? Later it will have more layers , every talk will have many comments. What I should do?

Should I build new entities "talks" and use Backbone - associations?

What is the right way to deal with models relations.

My code is based on backboneonrails tutorial and it is very structured: https://github.com/lipenco/talkingheads
I want to maintain good architecture while going into related models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not good to store objects in model's attribute. You can have problems with 'change' event not triggered if you change value of properties in attribute that is object.

So I think it's better to create separate model for talk. You can do all association work manually or use library for that: http://backbonerelational.org/